# Lapply function across specified excel sheets

Tags: r, excel, list, lapply

I have multiple excel files, with multiple sheets. I need to extract certain data from each sheet and combine all the data together. For one sheet I do the following:

```
supdata = read_excel("Data/Exercise/IDNo-03.xlsx", sheet="Supervised", skip = 2)
ID =  read_excel("Data/Exercise/IDNo-03.xlsx", sheet="Measurements",  col_names = FALSE)

id =  as.character( ID[1,1])%>%
  str_replace("Participant ", "")
mass = as.numeric(ID[3,5])
supdata = supdata%>%
    mutate(ID = id, Mass = mass)
```

This works. I need to do this for all the files.

I've tried this:

```
dir_path <- "Data/Exercise/"
list = list.files(path = dir_path, "*.xlsx")

all = lapply(list, function(x){
  supdata = read_excel(x, sheet="Supervised", skip = 2)
  ID =  read_excel(x, sheet="Measurements",  col_names = FALSE)
  
  id =  as.character( ID[1,1])%>%
    str_replace("Participant ", "")
  mass = as.numeric(ID[3,5])
  
  supdata = supdata%>%
    mutate(ID = id, Mass = mass) 
  
  })
```

`list` identifies the relevant files in the specified path, but I get an error:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘IDNo-03.xlsx’
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to approach this problem?
If I can get this bit working I will then do:

```
dat = do.call("rbind.data.frame", all)
```

Comment: I think you need `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files` and specify `pattern = "*\\.xlsx"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.files` without specifying the `full.names` return only the file names without the full path

```
list.files(file.path(getwd(), "Downloads"), pattern ="\\.csv")
#[1] "testing.csv"
```

If we specify the `full.names`

```
list.files(file.path(getwd(), "Downloads"), pattern ="\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)  
#[1]"/Users/akrun/Downloads/testing.csv"
```

---

When we loop over those files, without the path, it looks for the file in the working directory and thus gives the error